# I have a while loop and I want to call the variable multiple times is it possible?

Tags: java, while-loop

An example of this would be

```
i = 0;
while(i < 3) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner();
String variableIWantToCallLater = scan.nextLine();
}
```

User enters macaroni the first time sausage the second time and cheese the third time.

Is there anyway that I could have store/save the first two times the user enters the input? Or would I have to use something else?

Comment: Use an `ArrayList` and append to it each time: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp

Comment: also: declare and instantiate the Scanner before the loop.

Comment: And hint: dont try to invent all your code. Start by looking at working examples, from good books or tutorials to a certain degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array list to store all user inputs and use them later with something like this:

```
List<String> userInputs = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
   System.out.println("Enter a text: ");
   String variableIWantToCallLater = scan.nextLine();
   userInputs.add(variableIWantToCallLater);
}
//userInputs in this case will be what u saved to use when the user is done entering the data.
```

Full implementation, tested and working

```
public class Test {
    private List<String> getInputs(){        
        List<String> userInputs = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
           System.out.println("Enter a text: ");
           String variableIWantToCallLater = scan.nextLine();
           userInputs.add(variableIWantToCallLater);
        }
        return userInputs;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Test().getInputs());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm currently learning Java and didn't know much about arrays. This solves my problem!

Comment: its wrong completely . where is system.in? nextLine() will not work with loop here

Comment: @priyranjan That was an oversight, no need for a down vote, a simple correction could have still served. Anyway thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Rrichard ...still it will not work. nextLine() will fail when i=2.

Comment: @priyranjan This loop will allow the user to do three entries i.e macaroni, sausage and cheese just like the question stated. entry will start from 0. I have actually run it and it works.

Comment: one more time ,have  a  look  on your code.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException  you ll be getting error once you run your code .

Comment: @priyranjan I have updated my answer with the code which I've run successfully in my machine, there is no  java.util.NoSuchElementException that is logged.